# Make an API Request with Postman from Traefik/Docker (Reverse Proxy)

Tags: angular, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose, traefik

I'm using Traefik with Docker-Compose to host a full stack application using Angular/.Net Core/Postgres.

What I need to do is send an api request with Postman to see if I can get a response back so I can start building the front-end to make those requests.

The goal is to use the same port with dynamic routes to make these requests.

**localhost/**

**localhost/api/[request address]**

I'm new to Traefik and Docker so I've been using tutorials as references. This is the container for Traefik in my docker-compose file:

```
traefik:
    image: traefik:2.4
    command: --api.insecure=true --providers.docker
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
      - "443:443"
    command:
    # API Settings
      - --api.insecure=true
      - --api.dashboard=true
      - --api.debug=true
    # Log Settings
      - --log.level=DEBUG 
    # Provider Settings
      - --providers.docker=true
      - --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false
      - --providers.docker.network=glfmanager_network
    # Entrypoint settings
      - --entrypoints.glf.address=:80
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    networks:
      - glfmanager_network
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.rule=Host(`traefik.localhost`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.service=api@internal"
```

the container for the front-end:

```
client:
    depends_on: 
      - glfmanager.api
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}glf_ui_image
    build:
      context: ./client
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: "glf_ui_container"
    volumes:
      - /client/node_modules
      - ./client:/app
    networks:
      - glfmanager_network
      - backend_network
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.glf-web.rule=Host(`localhost`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.glf-web.entrypoints=glf"
```

Container for the api

```
glfmanager.api:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}glfmanager.api
    container_name: "glfmanager.api"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: GLFManager.Api/Dockerfile
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - **connection string stuff**
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    depends_on:
      - "glfmanager.db"
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.glf-api.entrypoints=glf"
      - "traefik.http.routers.glf-web.rule=Host(`localhost`) && PathPrefix('/api/')"
    networks:
      - glfmanager_network
      - backend_network
```

When I visit ***localhost*** I'm greeted by my Angular page. It's when I test the api using Postman, I get a 404 page not found. The link used is ***"localhost/api/[some req path]"*** which is what the backend is setup to listen to.

The expected response is to see json. Even if I don't have an access token, the response should at least be a 401 Unauthorized.

Please let me know your thoughts, or if you need any more details that I can provide.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any reason not to use app.UseSpa(...) in the `Startup.cs` `Configure` method as used in the SPA tutorial found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/angular?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio

In that configuration, the ASP.NET core container serves both the Angular app and the API. Keep in mind that this means both the api and the frontend need to be temporarily shut down every time either of them has to be updated.